# access-control-allow-origin not working?

Tags: .htaccess, cors

I've seen similar questions asked here but I am still unable to solve this issue.
I'm running Typekit and FontAwesome (from CDN) and I get the following error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://resource.com/example/example. Origin http://mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Now, the typekit font and fontawesome css stylesheet are loading perfectly fine, so I'm not sure why the error :\

I have already tried to setup CORS through .htaccess but even then I still get the error.
Does anyone have a recommendation for this problem?

This is happening in both, my local and production server.

Comment: CORS can only be set on the server you're loading *from*; is your .htaccess file being updated on your local machine or the one you're pulling content from?

Comment: Oh, that I wasn't sure of. If that's the case then Typekit should have those settings and I shouldn't be receiving said error, right?

Comment: You're correct. It may be the manner in which you're loading TypeKit; if you're requesting it from Javascript rather than within the HTML this could be a reason. Do you have sample code you can post that might clarify how you load it?